# R + Shiny: qr code generation and download

Tags: r, shiny, qr-code, shinyapps

I want to create an app where the user can input a link or some text and download the corresponding QR code as a pdf.
I have already the fundamental building blocks, but I cannot glue them together.
For instance, for the pure QR code generation part

```r
library(qrcode)



qr <- qr_code("https://www.wikipedia.org/")

pdf("qr_code.pdf")
plot(qr)
dev.off()
#> png 
#>   2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

for inputting text in Shiny

```r
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("caption", "Caption", "Your link/text here"),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)



server <- function(input, output) {
    output$value <- renderText({ input$caption })

}



shinyApp(ui, server)
#> PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
```

Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents

<sup>Created on 2022-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

and for saving a plot as a pdf in Shiny

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


df <- tibble(x=seq(10), y=seq(10))


ui <- fluidPage(
 sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

 downloadButton("save", "Download plot"),
 ),
 
mainPanel(
     plotOutput("tplot" ) 
)


)

)


server <- function(input, output) {

      tplot <- reactive({

plot(df$x, df$y)
          
      })

        output$tplot <- renderPlot({
tplot()
    })





# downloadHandler contains 2 arguments as functions, namely filename, content
  output$save <- downloadHandler(
    filename =  function() {
      paste("myplot.pdf")
    },
    # content is a function with argument file. content writes the plot to the device
    content = function(file) {

        pdf(file) # open the pdf device
      plot(x=df$x, y=df$y) # draw the plot
        dev.off()  # turn the device off
    
    } 
)

    
    
}










shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
```

Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents

<sup>Created on 2022-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Can anyone help me put all of this together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do this:

**UI**:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      textInput("link", "Enter Link here", "www.google.com"),
      downloadButton("save", "Download QR")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("tplot" ) 
    )
  )
)
```

`textInput` takes arguments `inputId`, `label`, and `value`.

1. `inputId` is what you'll refer to the input inside your code.
2. `label` tells what will be written over the input field. It is something that user can see and identify what to enter in the field.
3. 'value` is the default value that your input field will have. It can be blank.

**Server**:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  tplot <- reactive({
    qr <- qr_code(input$link)
    plot(qr)
    
  })
  output$tplot <- renderPlot({
    tplot()
  })
  
  # downloadHandler contains 2 arguments as functions, namely filename, content
  output$save <- downloadHandler(
    filename =  function() {
      paste("myplot.pdf")
    },
    # content is a function with argument file. content writes the plot to the device
    content = function(file) {
      pdf(file) # open the pdf device
      plot(qr_code(input$link)) # draw the plot
      dev.off()  # turn the device off
    } 
  )
}
```

Notice that I've used `qr_code` inside the `reactive` field so that you can use it further in output.
The shiny app will now, show the QR code as you keep typing inside the input field. Since it is reactive, it reacts to your input.

The download functionality also works as expected.

Comment: Happy New Year!